# Google Maps polygon contains location True False

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I've used Javascript+HTLM to show user location and have created polygons on google maps API. My issue is with creating labels/textboxes displaying "User is in polygon" and "User is not in polygon". This example code creates a red dot if the point clicked is in the polygon, and a green dot if the point clicked is out of the polygon. Instead of red and green dots, I want to have "In polygon" "Out of polygon" displayed in a text box that I can then record into a database.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Polygon arrays</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

 function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.269},
zoom: 5,
 });

var triangleCoords = [
 {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19},
 {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
 {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
 ];

 var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
  var resultColor =
    google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle) ?
    'red' :
    'green';

new google.maps.Marker({
  position: e.latLng,
  map: map,
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: resultColor,
    fillOpacity: .2,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: .5,
    scale: 10
  }
});
 });
 }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
     async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried using this code which logs "True" or "False" in the console but again, not in a textbox.

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, bermudaTriangle));
     });
     }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Big thanks for any and all help here.

Comment: There is no text box in your HTML. How did you try to put that text in a text box?  What text box were you planning on putting it in?

Comment: I was just put a label underneath the map that I'd like to have display the result.           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

Answer (score 0):

I had a label called Label1 and used this code which writes true in the label if point is in the polygon or false if the point is out of polygon.

```
     var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML =google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, bermudaTriangle);
        });
```